What does the error code in VS Code IntelliSense errors refer to?
Let's say I write a faulty piece of code in C++, such as:
const int x;

VS Code's IntelliSense will throw an error of the type:
const variable "x" requires an initializer C/C++(257)

I am curious what the error code between parentheses (here 257) refers to - is it quoting the ISO Standard?

"is it quoting the ISO Standard?..." Nope, it is quoting it's own documentation/implementation error code. Basically, 257 is vscode's internal error code.

C and C++ are different languages.

@UlrichEckhardt read the question closely ands look at the end of the error message. This is one of the rare cases where it is legit to use both C and C++ tags.

"piece of code in C/C++" still doesn't make sense, @Jabberwocky. Also, just because some too fails to make that distinction doesn't make it right either.

@UlrichEckhardt you're right, I would've thought that for a file written in C IntelliSense would raise the same error, which is why I included both, but it actually doesn't. I'll edit my question to remove the C reference.


is it quoting the ISO Standard?

No, it is not referring the ISO standard when it uses 257.
Instead it is referring to its own internal error code 257. VSCode has different error codes for different errors. Different error code list for vscode should be available at their official site.
